# C - Safely parse and send many strings in large endless stream

Tags: c, zeromq

I don't have much experience with C.

I have a small C program that connects to a practically infinite text stream (25Mb/s).

I want to send each line of the string as a separate message with zeromq.

So, I will be sending many thousands of messages per second, and before each message is sent I want to manipulate the string being sent over the socket:

Say I start with:

```
Quote {0.0.0.0} XXX <1>A<2>B<3>C
```

I want

```
XXX Quote <1>A<2>B<3>C
```

In a general sense, how can I do this safely so that I don't run into memory leaks? I would have something like this (Just an example, the `main` function would actually be a never ending loop with different chars):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* parse(const char* input) {

        char* output;
        char* input_copy = strdup(input);
        char* token;
        char* first;
        char* third;
        char* fourth;

        token = strtok(input_copy, " ");
        first = token;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                if (i == 1) third = token;
                if (i == 2) fourth = token;
        }

        asprintf(&output, "%s %s %s", third, first, fourth);
        return output;
        free(output);
}

int main(void)
{
        const char *a = "Quote {0.0.0.0} XXX <1>A<2>B<3>C";
        //SEND_MESSAGE(parse(a));
        return 0;
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: No. You cannot `free` after `return`. In fact, you must not put any statement after `return` as it will not be executed

Comment: Consider dropping dynamic allocation entirely, if this is a large, repetitive task. Using a single statically allocated buffer, large enough to hold the worst case, will be much faster.

Comment: Consider using `-Wall` for compiler option, it will help you to avoid bad practice

Comment: @Lundin that sounds like a good idea. This is definitely a large, repetitive (infinite for practical purposes) task. I am unsure of how that would work though. There is a maximum size that the messages (input) can have. So, should I create a buffer about that size (or larger?) use it to create and store the parsed string, and then clear it and repeat? Could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: @AllTheTime You'd take the input string and copy it to the static buffer at the same time as you parse through it. Then send the contents of the buffer. At next iteration, you simply overwrite the contents of the buffer - the null termination will ensure that only valid data gets used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know (or can determine with particularity) what the maximum size of each `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` will be, you can eliminate all possibility of a *memory leak* by simply using a fixed size buffer for each. You say your 25M/sec of text is broken up into *lines*, so presumably you are using *a line-oriented-input* function (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`) to read from the stream. In that case, you could also just use the maximum line length (X4) to insure your fixed buffers are adequate.

You are tokenizing into a `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` using a `space` as the delimiter, so why not use `sscanf`? If you want to use your `parse` function, just pass the buffers as parameters.

If you can determine a max and you are tokenizing on `space`, you could do something as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "Quote {0.0.0.0} XXX <1>A<2>B<3>C";
    char first[MAXC] = "",
         second[MAXC] = "",
         third[MAXC] = "",
         fourth[MAXC] = "";

    /* read a line from the stream and simply call sscanf */
    if (sscanf (a, " %s %s %s %s", first, second, third, fourth) == 4)
        printf ("%s %s %s\n", third, first, fourth);

    return 0;
}
```

(`printf` is just used for example, pass the results to your *zeromq* as required)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/staticbuf
XXX Quote <1>A<2>B<3>C
```

(that would have the side-effect of greatly simplifying your code and likely speed it up quite a bit as well).

If you can't, with any confidence, determine a max size, then you are stuck with the overhead of `malloc`/`free` (or using POSIX `getline` and letting it handle the allocation).

Comment: Thank you! This is incredibly helpful/illuminating.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Sometimes (most of the time) the KISS philosophy is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `main` like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "Quote {0.0.0.0} XXX <1>A<2>B<3>C";
    char *buff = parse(a);
    SEND_MESSAGE(buff);
    free(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

and remove the `free` after the `return` in `parse`. You also need to allocate enough space for `output`:

```
char *output = malloc(1024); //for example
```

As the comments on the question mention, it would be better to declare `output` as a global variable (so put the previous line outside `parse`), and `free` it at the very end of your program (outside the loop over the strings of the input stream). This makes the program much faster indeed.

Comment: This does NOT ANSWER to most important part of question: looping

Comment: Nothing wrong in the loop @JacekCz. He asks about memory leaks, and my solution DOES ANSWER it.

Comment: Agree (partially). Question is at basic level, has at this moment nothing to do with good, fast, lead free loop. Only in description